# How to add javascript to JIRA 7

Tags: jira

I have a JIRA server installed on my server I would like to add a javascript to all pages. any idea how?

I could not change any jsp file it seems that all are compiled could not be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If hacky solutions don't make you feel uncomfortable, you might be able to use the "Announcement Banner" to achieve this. You can insert html/css/javascript there and it will be displayed on each page in JIRA.

There's an example available [here](http://www.j-tricks.com/tutorials/jira-notification-messages).

The "Announcement Banner" documentation is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver072/configuring-an-announcement-banner-829826989.html).

Note that this only works on JIRA Server. On JIRA Cloud [the Announcement Banner only accepts text or wiki format](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-27864).